# how to format bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently editing my login page and I found that my bootstrap icon is not align as username.It supposed to be center but now it is slightly up in the username box field. how to edit to be center.

Secondly, how to set if the first time reload to the page, the icon not displayed until I start to type username.

```
    <h3 class="form-title">Login to your account</h3>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                      <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="loginForm.username.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username"
                                   ng-model="input.username" required>
                            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"
                                  ng-class="loginForm.username.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                        </div>
```

[my login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S6B3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for (I am currently editing my login page and I found that my bootstrap icon is not align as username.It supposed to be center but now it is slightly up in the username box field. how to edit to be center.)

- you can set it just by padding-top or padding-bottom

for (Secondly, how to set if the first time reload to the page, the icon not displayed until I start to type username.)

- you have to add JavaScript for Input on focus add css opacity 1. and by default add css opacity 0. refer below code.

CSS - `.your-container-class .glyphicon { opacity: 0;}`

JS - `$("#username").focusin(function() {
    $("#username").siblings(".glyphicon").css( "opacity", "1" );
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to adjust element alignments (in this case the icons) by adjusting it's margin using:

```
.your-container-class .glyphicon {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Be sure to wrap your form to a div with a class or id to avoid all glyphicon being styled throughout your application :-)